# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI with Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm having problem with making Spring Data Rest work, I have:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "account", path = "account")
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{
    Account findByUsername(String username);
}
```

However when resource `/account` is accessed from the client I can see from the log:

```
[INFO] WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/account] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

**servelet-context.xml**

```
<!-- <mvc:annotation-driven/> -->
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mycompany" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /static/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>   
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"/>
```

And I'm using Google App Engine (GAE) platform so I can't use Spring boot.

**Update:**

After adding:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration" />
```

When I run the app and access /account it throws:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

Comment: If you scan up your logs, you will see which request handlers were registered.

Comment: I can only see: [INFO] INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Root mapping to handler 'homeController'

Comment: Your configuration is possibly off then.

Comment: How do you bootstrap your app? What does your Spring configuration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Spring configuration, it seems you're not activating Spring Data REST at all. You need to declare a bean definition for the Spring Data Configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration" />
```

Comment: After I add this now it throws: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: … which is coming from GAE internals, so I am out of ideas.